# Prove limit by definition

Tags: calculus

> Prove by the definition that $\lim_{x\to 3}5x=15$

Let there be $\epsilon>0$ we need to find $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-3|<\delta$ then $|5x-15|<\epsilon$.

$|5x-15|=|5(x-3)|=5|x-3|<\epsilon$

So $5\delta<\epsilon\iff \delta = \lfloor{\frac{\epsilon}{5}\rfloor}$ so we will choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{5}$ so the required will take place.

Where am I getting wrong in the formalization of the proof?

Comment: you need  $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$  so how to choose it  $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5}$ ?

Comment: $\delta = \lfloor{\frac{\epsilon}{5}\rfloor}$

Comment: More precisely  $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \lfloor  \frac{\epsilon}{5}\rfloor  $, since what if   $\lfloor  \frac{\epsilon}{5}\rfloor =  \frac{\epsilon}{5 }$

Comment: Using the floor is wrong! The “if and only if” you state is wrong: $5\delta<\epsilon$ if and only if $\delta<\epsilon/5$. Note that if $\epsilon=0.1$, then $\lfloor \epsilon/5\rfloor=0$, to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $5|x-3| < \varepsilon$ iff $|x-3| < \varepsilon/5$; taking $\delta := \varepsilon/5$ suffices.

Answer (score 0):

The floor function should not be there. Simply choose $\delta = \epsilon/5$ will suffice and you should be able to work out the formal proof.